# Try to start azure devops release with python sdk

Tags: python, azure-devops

I try to start azuredevops release with the python sdk you can see this here

https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-devops-python-api

but the `create_release` function need two param the first is `project name` add other is `release_start_metadata`

when i try to call this function

`get_projects_response = core_release_client.get_release_definition(project='project_name', release_start_metadata=[{"definitionId":1}])`

the create_release function looks like this

```
def create_release(self, release_start_metadata, project):
    """CreateRelease.
    Create a release.
    :param :class:`<ReleaseStartMetadata> <azure.devops.v5_1.release.models.ReleaseStartMetadata>` release_start_metadata: Metadata to create a release.
    :param str project: Project ID or project name
    :rtype: :class:`<Release> <azure.devops.v5_1.release.models.Release>`
    """
```

but i dont now what the param release_start_metadata need
when i try to call this funciton `azure.devops.v5_1.release.models.ReleaseStartMetadata()`
i have nothing

it's is possible to just pass `definition-name` like `azcli`

```
az pipelines release create -p "project-name" --definition-name "deploy staging"
```

Comment: Not get your latest information. Just want to check whether below answer is helpful for you? If yes, you can accept the answer and we could archive this thread. Also, feel free to leave comment below if still has any puzzle about it:-)

Answer (score 0):

> i dont now what the param release_start_metadata need when i try to
> call this funciton
> azure.devops.v5_1.release.models.ReleaseStartMetadata() i have nothing

You need to initialize a "[release_start_metadata](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-python-api/blob/dev/azure-devops/azure/devops/v5_1/release/models.py#L2845)" object.

```
def __init__(self, artifacts=None, definition_id=None, description=None, environments_metadata=None, is_draft=None, manual_environments=None, properties=None, reason=None, variables=None):
    super(ReleaseStartMetadata, self).__init__()
    self.artifacts = artifacts
    self.definition_id = definition_id
    self.description = description
    self.environments_metadata = environments_metadata
    self.is_draft = is_draft
    self.manual_environments = manual_environments
    self.properties = properties
    self.reason = reason
    self.variables = variables
```